# Two dependent conditions in exclude DJANGO

Tags: python, sql, django

I want to check whether the current user already has the same movie id in his personal list or not. If he has it then I want to exclude that movie from my trending list.

I want it to be something like this.

**views.py**

```
trending = list(Movies.objects.exclude(mid in mymovies WHERE uid = request.user.id))
```

**models.py**

```
class Movies(models.Model):
    mid = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    rdate = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    cover = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    sequal = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    trailer = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title   

class MyMovies(models.Model):
    mid = models.ForeignKey(Movies, on_delete=CASCADE)
    uid = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    watched = models.BooleanField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
```

Comment: Please share your models.

Comment: added models in problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`.exclude(…)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) with:

```
trending = Movies.objects.exclude(mymovies__uid=request.user)
```

If you specified a [**`related_query_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) or a [**`related_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), then you need to use that to make a JOIN with your `Movies` model:

```
trending = Movies.objects.exclude(related_name_of_fk__uid=request.user)
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `MyMovie` instead of <s>`MyMovies`</s>.

---

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `_id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
> will automatically add a "twin" field with an `_id` suffix. Therefore it should
> be `user`, instead of <s>`uid`</s>.

Comment: understood the naming conventions, but quite not getting your solution I want to check that the movie should not be in mymovie with respect to the current user.

Comment: to be more specific I need to exclude the results of this SQL query -> SELECT mid FROM mymovies WHERE uid = request.user.id

Comment: @SakshamAgarwal: well the following will excude a `Movies` object, given there *exists* a `MyMovies` record that refers to that movie, and to the `request.user` as `uid`.

Comment: Oh I see, I will check it out whether this works for me or not and reach out soon. Thanks